# How can I build ghostscript with an alternative zlib?

Tags: ghostscript, zlib

I'm using ghostscript to generate rather large PDF files, and profiling has lead me to believe that a lot of time is spent compressing data.

For whatever reason, the ghostscript source tree ships with a copy of the zlib 1.2.11 source code, which is then compiled into the resulting `gs` executable.

I would like to benchmark other zlib implementations, notably [Cloudflare's](https://github.com/cloudflare/zlib) and possibly Intel's.

In ghostscript's `Makefile.in`, there's an interesting section:

```
# Define the directory where the zlib sources are stored.
# See zlib.mak for more information.

SHARE_ZLIB=@SHARE_ZLIB@
ZSRCDIR=@ZLIBDIR@
#ZLIB_NAME=gz
ZLIB_NAME=z
ZLIB_CFLAGS=@ZLIBCFLAGS@
```

And looking in `base/zlib.mak`:

```
# makefile for zlib library code.
# Users of this makefile must define the following:
#       GSSRCDIR - the GS library source directory
#       ZSRCDIR - the source directory
#       ZGENDIR - the generated intermediate file directory
#       ZOBJDIR - the object directory
#       SHARE_ZLIB - 0 to compile zlib, 1 to share
#       ZLIB_NAME - if SHARE_ZLIB=1, the name of the shared library
#       ZAUXDIR - the directory for auxiliary objects.
```

So, in theory, one should just compile zlib elsewhere, get an `.so` file (perhaps?), set `SHARE_ZLIB` to `1` and `ZLIB_name` to `/foo/bar/zlib_cloudflare/libz.so` and everything should be good. Except it doesn't work, and there's zero documentation.

Comment: We don't expect people to meddle with the internals of Ghostscript really which is why there is 'zero documentation'. If you want to you are of course perfectly entitled to do so (it is open source), but you are on your own. While it may once have been possible to have zlib as a shared library I wouldn't count on it working now, and I wouldn't be too certain about replacing it either; there are an awful lot of assumptions in the Ghostscript code base and it would not surprise me to discover that it won't work with anything else. But good luck, let us know how you get on.

Comment: As far as I can tell from a quick look, the CloudFlare (and presumably Intel) changes appear to be to use SIMD and possibly other similar CPU-specific code (ag AVX). Since that appears to be all that is changed, you should simply be able to replace the zlib directory in the Ghostscript tree with the one you want to try. Assuming it respects autoconf, then it should all work on Linux and include the optimisations.

Comment: KenS, thank you for your comments. I've also explored the direction of just replacing the zlib files with a different set. Cloudflare's does contain extra files (*_simd.c, possibly others.) so a little hacking might be required.

Comment: IT'S WORKING! Right now it's a terrible, hacky mess. Once it's cleaned up and better understood, I'll post it, but suffice to say I went the route of just dropping in the new zlib. There's a few additional files (`adler32_simd.o`, `crc32_simd.o`) that need to be added, and the `base/zlib.mak` file needs to be altered so it uses the build options from the optimized zlib.